# Should keyboard navigation be enabled for field option/helper buttons in a form?

Tags: forms, navigation

Some fields in a form have additional options buttons. A common example is rich-text editors (like the one I'm using right now) have many buttons associated with them that control formatting (e.g. bold, italic).

Should the buttons for these types of options be navigable from keyboard input (tab)?

On one hand, all users should be able to access these buttons, so they should be keyboard navigable.

However, they get in the way when trying to just tab through inputs in the form and can slow the user down, so perhaps they should not be keyboard navigable. (It seems Stack has chosen to not allow keyboard navigation through the formatting buttons for rich-text editing).

Also perhaps the buttons should not allow keyboard navigation, but there should always be another way to take the same action (e.g. cmd/ctrl + B gives bold text).

---

I'm using rich-text as an example here because it is common, but I'd like to avoid answers that are specific to rich-text. Specifically, I am working with forms that have options like Edit, Clear, and Reset for each field. It could be argued that these buttons are not strictly necessary and therefore disallowing keyboard navigation is not an issue.

Comment: Are you using browser or your own desktop application to work with your forms?

Comment: @Serg this is for a site in the browser.

Comment: I think the answer will depend on who your users are. Also, accessibility should be a consideration. For example, are you designing for users who often use keyboard shortcuts? can you offer them without affecting non-shortcut users? What about using key combinations and not tab? Look at Google Docs for examples.